# Are FPS browser-dependent in games like Quake Live or Battlefield Heroes?

Tags: quake-live, battlefield-heroes

Could the number of frames per seconds you get in browser-based games like **Quake Live**, **Battlefield Heroes** or **Free Realms** be affected by the browser version or browser type?

I mean choosing **Chrome** instead of **Firefox**, for example, could affect FPS or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, no, not directly.

The game is executing "Out-of-Process", which means that the browser is not technically controlling the game, but rather sending commands to it.

However, The browser will consume memory, and possibly CPU cycles which could have a negative impact.  This will, of course, be the same as having the browser open at any other time.